# Error when sending email using Outlook API

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, outlook

Am trying to send email using MS Outlook API through from my .Net 4 C# application on a Windows 7 machine.
Am able to send it successfully if I dont set any sender's email Id in the code.

But when I invoke SendUsingAccount(), I get an access violation error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

Could you please advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.This problem is solved now.It was happening because MS office on my machine was corrupted.